# Excel countif(s) multiples

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to calculate the count of multiple occurrences of a figure using countif.

I have the range set but I need a calculation which can count in multiples of 50 without me having to type thousands of versions of countif (=COUNTIF(B2:B5,">=50")-COUNTIF(B2:B5,">100" etc.).

```
Data    Count

50         1
70         1
80         1 
10         0
150        3
```

This data should show 6 but at the moment I'm getting 4.

Comment: Please show us more of your data and more of your desired answer.

Comment: I see 6... 1+1+1+3 = 6

Answer (score 1):

First you can start by making bins. you can make it with Data analysis tool or half manual

Like in the example, on A2 enter 0 and on b2 enter `=a2+50`

Same goes for a3 enter `=b2` and last on a4 `=a3+50`

Now you can drag it down as much as you like.

Instaed of using countif use sumif finction. let's assume your data is on cloumn `H` and the values you want to sum are in column `I`, then  on `c2` enter 
`=SUMIFS(I:I,H:H,">"&A2,H:H,"<="&B2)`

you can drag it down as much as you like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Excels [`ROUNDDOWN`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rounddown.php) function:

e.g. for B2: `=ROUNDDOWN(A2/50,0)`

Comment: That provides the same result as the screenshot in the OP, but it does add up to 6, which is something I was questioning. :)

Comment: I admit that my answer is based on many assumptions about what the OP wants and is therefore just as good as the question itself.